# Could not find implicit value for parameter flash

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm trying to port some code from Play Framework Java to Play Framework Scala but I'm having some issues with porting a tag.

The tag in question in the Java version checks the contents of the Flash scope and creates notifications to the user according to its values (error, success, etc).

I tried to create a Scala view (`flag.scala.html`):

```
@()(implicit flash:play.mvc.Scope.Flash)

@if(flash.get("error")) {
    <p style="color:#c00">
        @flash.get("error")
    </p>
}
```

Which I call from `main.scala.html` via:

```
@views.Application.html.flag()
```

The error I get is:

> The file {module:.}/tmp/generated/views.html.main.scala could not be
>   compiled. Error raised is : could not find implicit value for
>   parameter flash: play.mvc.Scope.Flash

The call to the new tag is correct, as if I replace the content by some String that's shown in the browser.

I'm sure it's something stupid but I got stuck. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the details of Play, but this compile error is saying you should either:

1. Pass an explicit instance of `play.mvc.Scope.Flash` in the call to `flag()`,

   ```
   views.Application.html.flag()(myFlash)
   ```

   or
2. Make an implicit instance of `Flash` available in the scope where `flag()` is called. You could do this by importing the contents of some object (`import some.path.FlashImplicits._`) or by defining the implicit instance yourself,

   ```
   implicit val myFlash: play.mvc.Scope.Flash = ...
   ...
   views.Application.html.flag()
   ```

So the real question becomes: where do you want to get this `Flash` instance from?

Comment: Yes, the second fix worked perfectly with Play: @()(implicit flash:play.mvc.Scope.Flash = play.mvc.Scope.Flash.current()) on the tag declaration of variables. Thanks a million sir!

Comment: It looks like you went with option #3: Give the implicit parameter a default value. That works too. Note that you don't actually need to make it "implicit" here, but it doesn't hurt. Happy to help.

Answer (score 4):

You should not create an implementation for "implicit flash : Flash" on your own. Just add a "implicit request" to your action and it should work.

More details is here at the end of the page: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/ScalaSessionFlash

Comment: I have added implicit request, but it doesn't work.. when I try to have implicit flash, it doesnt work too.. play is quite a nuisance especially with changes on every minor release

Answer (score 2):

Ivan had the right suggestion, adding "implicit request".  However, his link seems outdated.  If you want a more explicit explanation, check out my answer to a similar question, here:

[How to pass flash data from controller to view with Play! framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15531455/how-to-pass-flash-data-from-controller-to-view-with-play-framework/18154587#18154587)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but looking at the documentation i found the following:

> If the error ‘could not find implicit value for parameter flash:
>   play.api.mvc.Flash’ is raised then this is because your Action didn’t
>   import a request object. Add an “implicit request=>”

of course the implicit Flash must appear in every view if you have nested views like:

```
@(implicit flash: Flash){

@main(){<h1>hello</h1>}

}
```

this view does not use flash scope but if main uses it, should be declared in views using main because the compiler will complain.

source: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaSessionFlash