# Can I call session in template/view on Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm new at using Play Framework 2.0 (I am using Scala) and have a question about sessions.

I come from a Ruby on Rails background, so I tend to think of everything that I learn in Play Framework with respect to Ruby on Rails.

With that in mind, is there any way for me to call stuff stored in the Session while I am in the view?

If I have "hello" -> "world" stored in the Session, I want to be able to do something like @session.get("hello") and be able to use "world" in the view. Is this possible?

The other option I see is to store the value in a variable in the controller, and pass that along to the view by doing something like OK( var ), but that way seems kind of clunky especially if I start using more variables.

Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Sessions in Play store in cookies and are really just for cross-request data.  If that is what you want then you can use `@session.get("hello")` but what you might actually be after is a way to pass stuff from controllers to templates without having to specify them as parameters.  In that case, see the very detailed answer to that question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9632085/77409

Comment: session doesn't seem to be in scope when I try this method?

Comment: See the other answer here for more details.

Answer (score 11):

Yes you can use `@session.get("hello")` in template, however it looks that you need to specify at least implicit parameter named 'session' at the beginning of the template when using templates with Scala controllers:

```
@()(implicit session: play.api.mvc.Session)
```

Also there is `flash` scope - it differs from `session` that it lives only for one request and is not signed. So it is most often used just for transporting error/inf messages.

See [Session and flash](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/ScalaSessionFlash) scopes doc

Finally as each template is just a Scala function, you can also call some action from your controller and retrieve session data

Comment: I tried putting "(implicit session: play.api.mvc.Session)" at the beginning of my template next to the @() where I pass in my arguments, but when I try calling @session I get an ERROR, not found: value session

Comment: When I try adding @(implicit session: play.api.mvc.Session) instead, I get a different error: '=>' expected but ')' found

Comment: Did you set some session before in any controller ? Check cookies for the domain, they are stored there.

Comment: It seems like when I put "(implicit session: play.api.mvc.Session)" next to the parameters, it just shows up on my page as HTML plaintext. How do I make play read it for what it's supposed to be?

Answer (score -3):

You can definetly call `ur` session in play templates.

Try this code - it works in views:

```
$session.session_variable_name;
```