# play 2.1-- save and retrieve variables in session scope in both java controller and scala template

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

i am very new to play framework and started using play2.1 with Java.
My query may be basic but couldnt find in the documentation and with search and tried many ways...

I want to know how to save and retrieve a variable in session both in java controller and scala template...

below is one of the ways i tried..

public class Application extends Controller {
    static Form userForm = Form.form(User.class);

```
public static Result index() {
    play.mvc.Controller.session("accStatus",0);
    return ok(index.render());
}
```

but the problem with this is , dont know how to retrieve accStatus from session in scala template...

can some one look into this and guide to do...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I call session in template/view on Play Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10888407/can-i-call-session-in-template-view-on-play-framework)