# Server Sent Events on Play framework using Java

Tags: java, playframework, server-sent-events

I am completely new Play framework and Scala. I am trying to push some events from the server to the browser using Html5 -server sent events and play framework.

I came across this example in Scala. I tried implementing action composition in java by extending play.mvc.Action.Simple. I am not sure how to set the response headers in the action composition.

http://benquasmalltalk.blogspot.fr/2012/04/hub-interesting-but-undocumented.html

The data I am sending is coming from a database and not an enumeration. Any pointers will be helpful

Comment: Hi, you can see a solution here

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/play-framework/1yF4LtlpgzU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this by using the websocket example:
[websocket-chat](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/tree/master/samples/java/websocket-chat)

And for action composite (in java), have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629250/how-to-avoid-passing-parameters-everywhere-in-play2)