# How to implement widgets on PlayFramework2?

Tags: model-view-controller, widget, playframework-2.0

## Question

How can I implement a widget (resulting from database calls) to be present on each page of the website?

## Context

I have a traditionnal web application with a sidebar. The sidebar contains data such as :

- Username,
- Details about the account (last connection and other)
- Personnalized message based on profile of the user.
- And other data extracted from the database.

## Solutions so far

As shown in the official documentation, it is possible to render template inside of a template. Which is an interesting feature but it is not enough. Since I need data from the database to be rendered in my widget.

That would imply :

1. Getting all the data needed for the sidebar somewhere,
2. Passing that data from each controller to each view,
3. Finally in each template, call an external template with the given data.

What I would like to do is something as exists in the Symfony2 framework. I would like to be able to call a controller directly.

```
{% render MyController:MyActionMethod %}
```

How can one implement this kind of mecanism?

PS : Yes, I've searched around a bit. Found this question "similar question" : [How to avoid passing parameters everywhere in play2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629250/how-to-avoid-passing-parameters-everywhere-in-play2)

Answer (score 1):

There are two solutions, you described first - it's passing data from the controller as some kind of object and then using `tags` for rendering it.

Second solution is reverse, as in `Play 2` each template is just a Scala function, you can also just call some method in your controller, which will get required data and render the subtemplate.

ie. to access `controllers.MyController.myMethod(Integer a, Integer b)` from template use

```
<div>
  @MyController.myMethod(1,2) 
</div>
```

Comment: Cool stuff, if it indeed works. I will give it a try this evening. The one problem I see with this solution is that I will need the request. Meaning, I will have to pass the request along on all templates.

Comment: `request` is implicit in all templates (ie it is available directly)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a static method in a controller which returns a play.api.templates.Html (or a play.mvc.Content) instead of a Result.

```
public static Content widget() {

   Data fetchedData = fetchDataFromTheDatabase();

   return views.html.widget.render(fetchedData);
}
```

And in your view, simply call this static method.