# Java Play 2 - Templating

Tags: java, templates, playframework-2.0

I built my webapp from the sample "forms".  Forms has a template called "main.scala.html" with the fixed navbar of twitter bootstrap. It's really easy to use , I just can include it in all my templates.

But now I have a small problem.

I want to render two differnt things in this navbar. A login button if the user has not signed in, and a logout button if he has singend in.

The annoying part would be that I would have to do this for **all** my templates.

- Is this the correct way to do it?
- Or is there a better solution for this problem?

edit:

Maybe I can read the session in the template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can read the session from the template, but I suggest you to read this question and answer which may fit your need: [How to avoid passing parameters everywhere in play2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629250/how-to-avoid-passing-parameters-everywhere-in-play2)