# Making a variable accessible in all Play 2.0 project views

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

It is sometimes desirable to share context variables with all views, such as the current user or navigational state.  Looking through the documentation, I haven't been able to find a way to share such global context variables accessible to the template engine in all views.

Is this provided by the framework, or am I better off explicitly passing these variables to all views, perhaps by writing a wrapper method called in all controllers whose views need these global variables?

Comment: You should take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629250/how-to-avoid-passing-parameters-everywhere-in-play2/9632085#9632085

Answer (score 0):

You can use for that [Session and Flash scopes](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/JavaSessionFlash)

```
public static Result index() {
    // session is good for storing session data such as for an example logged user's info
    session("username", "John Doe");

    // flash is available only for next request (in this case for view rendering process)
    flash("navId", "mainPage");

    return ok(index.render("ellou' World"));
}
```

`index.scala.html`

```
@(message: String)

@main(message) {
    @if(flash.get("navId")=="mainPage"){<h1>Great! You're on main page again</h1>}
    <div>You're logged as @session.get("username")</div>
}
```

of course for data which are individual for each page (like sample `navId`) you can also pass it to the view, where you can declare required type other than `String`.