# How do I access the Global object from a view?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I know I could just pass the view the Global object instance, but that seems silly since I want to access a static field.

Comment: It is a bad idea. What's the purpose of this static field ? Please show some code.

Comment: The static field is containing the version string of my application.

Comment: You should take a look at the implicit parameters: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629250/how-to-avoid-passing-parameters-everywhere-in-play2/9632085#9632085

Comment: I solved the problem by using [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10015611/309483), brought to me by nico_ekito.