# Change language of text in template in play framework 2.1.1

Tags: scala, templates, web, internationalization, playframework-2.1

I want the user of the application can change the language in my play2 (play 2.1.1, scala 2.10.1) web application. I use @Messages.get(...) in my templates for i18n.

I have

```
application.langs="en,ru"
```

in application.conf. I pass "en" or "ru" to that method:

```
def index = Action {
   Ok(views.html.index())
}

def changeLanguage(lang:String) = Action {
  implicit request =>
    Logger.logger.debug("Change user lang to : " + lang)
    val referrer = request.headers.get(REFERER).getOrElse(HOME_URL)
    Redirect(referrer).withLang(Lang(lang))
}
```

routes:

```
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index
GET     /index                      controllers.Application.changeLanguage(lang ?= "ru")
```

the template bunch (views.html.index):

```
@()(implicit l: Lang)

@import play.i18n.Messages

...

<a href="/about">@Messages.get("about")</li>

...

<a href="index?lang=ru" id="ru"></a>
<a href="index?lang=en" id="en"></a>
...
```

After redirecting the page, I see it on the same language. :(

I was read many old answers: implicit language parameter in my template does not work, redirect or action with withLang(...) method call too. Did not have a good solution so long time?

Comment: It should work with the `.withLang(...)` method. Could you try and change `(implicit l: Lang)` to `(implicit l:play.api.i18n.Lang)` and `@import play.i18n.Messages` to `@import play.api.i18n.Messages`?

Comment: @EECOLOR, it did not work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made it work, so there are my changes. In app code (without an request instance play does not know where to get the cookie with the language?):

```
def index = Action {
 implicit request=>
   Ok(views.html.index())
}
```

And in the template (play.api.i18n imports automatically):

```
@()(implicit l: Lang)

...

<a href="/about">@Messages("about")</li>

...

<a href="index?lang=ru" id="ru"></a>
<a href="index?lang=en" id="en"></a>
...
```

Comment: Nice job! Then, [here is a more generic solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629250/how-to-avoid-passing-parameters-everywhere-in-play2): you can define you implicit request on every actions with less code.

Comment: Is it possible to avoid to write the `implicit l: Lang` part in each template and only define it in the main maybe?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and added my own message-resolution class over the play.i18n one.

For message resolution, you can have a example here (in Java): https://github.com/adericbourg/proto-poll/blob/dev/app/util/user/message/Messages.java#L76

And my controller changeLang's method calls this: https://github.com/adericbourg/proto-poll/blob/dev/app/util/security/CurrentUser.java#L71

It do not believe it is a good solution (it requires more code and I'm a lazy guy) but it works. Hope this can help...

Comment: I found a simpler solution