# Play 2.0 java - get list of models from http context

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I store a list of models in Http.context, then I'm not able to loop through it in the view.

Index action :

```
@With(MembershipAction.class)
public static Result index() {
...
```

Action composition :

```
public class MembershipAction extends Action.Simple {
@Override
public Result call(Context ctx) throws Throwable {

    Member member = Membership.getUser();
    if (member != null) {
        // MGroup.findInvolving(member)= List<play.db.ebean.Model> 
        // code : find.where().eq("members.id", member.id).findList();
        ctx.args.put("groups", MGroup.findInvolving(member));
    }
    return delegate.call(ctx);
}
}
```

Template view #1 :

```
@ctx().args.get("groups")
```

Output : 
BeanList size[6] hasMoreRows[false] list[models.MGroup@51, models.MGroup@3d, models.MGroup@2a, models.MGroup@29, models.MGroup@15, models.MGroup@1]

Template view #2 (not working) :

```
@for(group <- ctx().args.get("groups") ){
    @group.name
}
```

Output : 
Compilation Error / value map is not a member of Object

NOTE :
The method described here didnt work either : [How to avoid passing parameters everywhere in play2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629250/how-to-avoid-passing-parameters-everywhere-in-play2)

Trying the snippet "@Menus" was unknown...

Answer (score 0):

`ctx().args` gives you a map of Strings to Objects. So when you get something from this map, it's of type `Object`. I think your template fails compilation because you're trying to loop over an object.

The quickest way to fix this is to perform a cast in your template:

```
@for(group <- ctx().args.get("groups").asInstanceOf[List[models.MGroup]]) {
  @group.name
}
```

In my opinion the better fix would be to:

1. Change your template #2 to take in a list of model objects as an input parameter. Take a look at the template syntax in the Play documentation, and in particular how to define template input parameters.
2. Change the Java actions that render this template to get the list of model objects from the HTTP context in Java-land, passing them into the template at render time (after doing some null checking and type checking).

This way the code is more robust to data not being in the context, and also you maintain type safety in your template. Since the list would be fed into your template as an input parameter, you wouldn't need to look in `ctx().args` in your template, and you thus wouldn't need to perform a cast.

Comment: Thanks it worked. I know why the "@Menus" solution was not working before. I needed to import the Action class in the view  in combination with a static method to return the list :

`public static List<MGroup> groups() {
        return (List<MGroup>) Http.Context.current().args.get("groups");
    }
`

Comment: View snippet : `@for(group <- MembershipAction.groups() )`

Comment: Ok, I see what you're doing. You've added a convenience method on ``MembershipAction`` for retrieving the model objects you've added to the context map. That's a good approach too.