# Dynamic content in the root template in Play framework (Scala)

Tags: scala, playframework

I am learning the Play framework & was wondering how to create a dynamic sidebar/footer that would appear in the root template & I wouldn't need to pass the data for it explicitly when rendering every single view. I read through [the docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaTemplates), and there was nothing about this.

In Django I would create a custom template tag for this. Is there anything similar in Play as well? What would be the best / typical approach to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[How to avoid passing parameters everywhere in play2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629250/how-to-avoid-passing-parameters-everywhere-in-play2) and http://jazzy.id.au/default/2012/10/26/passing_common_state_to_templates_in_play_framework.html
are quite helpful.

For example you can have the templates footer.scala.html, main.scala.html and header.scala.html.

main.scala.html can look like:

```
@(title: String)(content: Html)(implicit x: SomeType)

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="@routes.Assets.at("images/favicon.png")">
        <script src="@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/jquery-1.9.0.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        @header() @* include the header *@
        @content  @* will resolve to "the content" for index.scala.html *@
        @footer() @* include the footer *@
    </body>
</html>
```

And an page template for example index.scala.html:

```
@(message: String)(implicit x: SomeType)

@main("Welcome to Play 2.1") {
    the content
}
```

The footer or the header can consume x: SomeType as implicit method parameters to deliver dynamic content.