# Play framework 2.1.3 Intercepting object from controller to view

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0

is it possible to intercept the object when passing it from the controller to the view?

I want to append to the model some information before using it in the view.

**EDIT:** one of the things I want to accomplish with that is to populate the Model object with a list of its attributes to be used by the template.

I'm constructing the template dynamically for every field in the object and somehow using the `obj.getClass().getDeclaredFields()` really doesn't look like a good choice to put into the template. Or maybe I'm wrong and this is the right way to approach this.

hope this will make my question a little bit more clear.

**EDIT2 :** maybe extend the play.api.templates.Html?

[play framework 2.1.3 extend play.api.templates.Html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19482375/play-framework-2-1-3-extend-play-api-templates-html)

Thank you

Comment: Why can't you append the information in the controller before you pass it? There really isn't anything special that happens when passing parameters to a view. A view is really just a function that returns an Html object to the controller, and the controller serves that to user.

Comment: I'd have to repeat the same piece of code over for every call I'm making to that template. I'd rather define it once in some manner.

Comment: You're still not making it clear as to what you want to append to what. This could probably be accomplished with implicit parameters, or by creating your own `Action`, or even overriding `Ok`. Based on the information given, I don't know which would suit you.

Comment: edited the question. Sorry if it wasn't clear enough from the beginning

Comment: extending the play.api.templates.Html? edited the question

Comment: Can you be more specific what you really want? It sounds like an extracted method which calls the template with your hook code would be enough to serve your purpose.

Comment: How more specific can I be? I have a model. I'm passing it from the controller to the view. I want to populate an attribute of this model object with some value. I can do this every time manually, but I want it to be done automatically, probably somehow with a hook like you said.
`User u = User.find.byId(id);`
`u.bla = "blabla";`
`return ok(views.html.user.read.render(u));`

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to use an implicit parameter in all your templates.

Read this topic for more details: [How to avoid passing parameters everywhere in play2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629250/how-to-avoid-passing-parameters-everywhere-in-play2)