# play framework 2.1.3 extend play.api.templates.Html

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.1

Just wondering if it's possible and if yes how hard it is to extend the play.api.templates.Html class.

```
import java.lang.StringBuilder;

public class MyHtml extends play.api.templates.Html {

}
```

gives me the error:

`error: constructor Html in class Html cannot be applied to given types;`

this gives the same:

```
public class MyHtml extends play.api.templates.Html {
    String text;

    public MyHtml(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`play.api.templates.Html`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.templates.Html) is written in Scala not Java, so it uses not `java.lang.StringBuilder` but [`scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder).

This compiles (I am not saying, that is useful or even good practice):

```
package views;

public class MyHtml extends play.api.templates.Html {
    private String text;

    public MyHtml(String text) {//please take care of HTML injection!!!
        super(scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder$.MODULE$.newBuilder());
        this.text = text;
    }

    @Override
    public String body() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, it compiles. But the reason why I wanted to do that is to call MyHtml from the controller like that:
`views.MyHtml.user.read.render( ... ` is it doable?

Comment: The real Scala templates provide the method 'render' for the Java API to generate an instance of HTML. MyHtml is already of the type 'Html' so you would use it like 'return ok(new views.MyHtml("foo"));'. It is not a good idea to lose the Scala templates, they are typesafe and protect you in a lot of cased for security problems.

Comment: `return ok(new views.MyHtml("foo"));` This doesn't work. the page is blank.

Comment: I also updated my answer when I wrote my comment. I override the method body(),