# Playframework(Scala): passing user model around

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I wonder what's the best practise for passing user 'model' around. I take http request and convert it to user model in my controller. I don't want to explicitly add an argument to all the templates for this model, and neither to main. 
What are the best practises for doing this?

THanks.

Comment: I think this thread will answer your question :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629250/how-to-avoid-passing-parameters-everywhere-in-play2

Comment: @Moebius: It did. Very nice explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are logging in, and the user is your authenticated user, then you should put the user in a WrappedRequest and make your request implicit in your templates.  If you use something like SecureSocial, then UserAwareAction will provide you with a RequestWithUser (see http://securesocial.ws/guide/user-service.html) and you can do things like

```
@()(implicit req:RequestWithUser)

Email = @{req.user.map(_.email)}
```

in your template.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Session scope.

Here is documentation for Play 2.0

http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.2/ScalaSessionFlash

So for example, on the login, add the user to the Session

And on logout remove the user from the Session

Cheers!