# how to call controller class in the views in play framework 2.5

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a controller class as below

```
class MenuAccessor @Inject()  extends securesocial.core.SecureSocial{
  def findAllMenus(): List[Menu] = {
  MorphiaHelper.datastore.find(classOf[Menu]).order("+order").toList
  }
}
```

I used to directly call it in the views in play 2.3.x as

```
  @for(menu <- MenuAccessor.findAllMenus()) {
                    <li class="@menu.menuliclass">
```

Does it mean that i have to create routes in order to call it in play 2.5?

Answer (score 0):

Routes will help you only if you want to get a link to the action (i.e. reverse routing).

You want to get data from some static method - then just call it from the template.  Something like this (do not forget packages):

```
object MenuAccessor{
  def findAllMenus(): List[Menu] = {
    MorphiaHelper.datastore.find(classOf[Menu]).order("+order").toList
  }
}

....

@for(menu <- MenuAccessor.findAllMenus()) {
                <li class="@menu.menuliclass">
```

However, I prefer to pass parameters [as it described in the documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTemplates):

```
@(products: List[Product])

<ul>
@for(p <- products) {
  <li>@p.name ($@p.price)</li>
}
</ul>
```

Play 2.5 is all about injection, so getting some data from the static objects or function is not a good idea for the future. Better to refactor your code to pass data as parameters into a template.

If you want "to avoid passing parameters everywhere in play2", then look this very good answer [How to avoid passing parameters everywhere in play2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629250/how-to-avoid-passing-parameters-everywhere-in-play2) (it's old but still usable)