# Variable in Play Framework 2.x Template

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, twirl

I browsed the web, but did not find an answer anywhere. If I missed something, please point me to a tutorial.

So I want to define a variable in a Play Framework template and, of course, use it later on.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
@if(menuitems.fetchFromVerySlowDatabase() != null) {
<ul>
    @for(menuitem <- menuitems.fetchFromVerySlowDatabase()) {
        <li><a href="@menuitem.getUrl()">menuitem.getTitle()</a></li>
    }
</ul>
}
```

I know I can cache `menuitems.fetchFromVerySlowDatabase` but what I am really looking for is something like that:

```
@menuitems_from_database = menuitems.fetchFromVerySlowDatabase();
@if(menuitems_from_database != null) {
<ul>
    @for(menuitem <- menuitems_from_database) {
        <li><a href="@menuitem.getUrl()">menuitem.getTitle()</a></li>
    }
</ul>
}
```

Thank you!

I am using Java as programming language.

Best,
schube

Comment: I know this does not answer your question, but you should probably do any heavy computations before invoking your template, and pass the result as parameter, instead of doing things inside the template, which should only be used to show things.

Comment: I agree, but: I need the menu items on every page, so I am fetching them in the template, otherwise every action in every controller would need to pass the menu items to the template system. Or at least, this is what I think. Do you have a better solution? Thank you!

Comment: If you need them on every page, you might want to load them as few times as possible. Depending on when their base is updated you might consider loading them once and forall as a value in your controller, or with some kind of cache system to avoid fetching them on every page, especially if, as the name seems to indicate, the action takes a long time. You may then create a function that pass this value to your template invoker.

Comment: Yes, I am trying to load it as few times as possible. Actually, this is almost solved (with caching). But I really want to avoid to pass the menu items as a parameter to each template seperately.

Comment: About a menu. There is a good description http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629250/how-to-avoid-passing-parameters-everywhere-in-play2, I can add only that you also could add cache, play has a cache API as well: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaCache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remember to do it in one line

```
@import scala.Predef; var menuitems_from_database = menuitems.fetchFromVerySlowDatabase();
```

An example of the live code (modification of the `index.scala.html` from the default template):

```
@import scala.Predef; var menuitems_from_database = new java.util.ArrayList[String]()
@(message: String)

@{
  menuitems_from_database.add("1")
  menuitems_from_database.add("2")
  ""
}

@main("Welcome to Play") {
    @if(menuitems_from_database != null) {
            <ul>
                @for(menuitem <- menuitems_from_database) {
                    <li><a href="@menuitem">@menuitem</a></li>
                }
            </ul>
        }
}
```

Resulting HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>            
        <title>Welcome to Play</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/assets/stylesheets/main.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="/assets/images/favicon.png">
        <script src="/assets/javascripts/hello.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <ul>
                    <li><a href="1">1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="2">2</a></li>
            </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I don't understand.
I changed the code to:


    var menuitems_from_database = menuitems.fetchFromVerySlowDatabase()
    @if(menuitems_from_database != null) {
     <ul>
            @for(menuitem <- menuitems_from_database) {
     ......

and some variantes with @var... and so on, but nothing compiles.
Can you please provide some more lines of code.

Thank you!

Comment: Works! Thank you!

Comment: One small comment: Now "true" is printed into the HTML where the variable is assigned.

Comment: because every statement must return something to the template, so just use it like in my example in the part where I add elements to the list `@{ ... ""}` so you return an empty string